# Uint8List to double in flutter dart

Tags: flutter, android-studio, dart, bluetooth

I wa using flutter bluetooth serial package to recieve data from a microcontroller. When i send integer values from the microcontroller, I get the values in this form:
[64], [144, 22]] the last number in the list(22) is the actual number i sent. however, everytime i send any values i get these two values as well [64], [144,...].
The other thing is when I send a float value from the micro controller, i receive it as int and when I try to convert the data type to double, I get an error like this:

> The argument type 'void Function(double)' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'void Function(Uint8List)?'.
>
> The argument type 'double' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'List'.

below is the snippet of the code where the first error arise

```
List<List<double>> chunks = <List<double>>[];

_getBTConnection(){
    BluetoothConnection.toAddress(widget.server.address).then((_connection){
      connection = _connection;
      isConnecting = false;
      isDisconnecting = false;
      setState(() {});

      connection.input?.listen(_onDataReceived).onDone(() {
        if(isDisconnecting){
          print("Disconnecting locally");


        }else{
          print("Disconnecting remotely");

        }
        if(mounted){
          setState(() {});
        }
        Navigator.of(context).pop();

      });

    }).catchError((error){
      Navigator.of(context).pop();

    });
  }
```

And below is the snippet of the second error arising:

```
  void _onDataReceived(double data){
    if(data != null && data > 0){
      chunks.add(data);
     

    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(" chunks: , $chunks " );
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have a sequence of 8 (8-bit) bytes in a `Uint8List`, you can obtain a [`ByteBuffer`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteBuffer-class.html) or [`ByteData`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-typed_data/ByteData-class.html) view of it to parse those bytes into a 64-bit `double`.

For example:

```dart
import 'dart:typed_data';

void main() {
  // Big-endian byte sequence for pi.
  // See <https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-precision_floating-point_format>
  var bytes =
      Uint8List.fromList([0x40, 0x09, 0x21, 0xFB, 0x54, 0x44, 0x2D, 0x18]);
  var doubleValue = bytes.buffer.asByteData().getFloat64(0);
  print(doubleValue); // Prints: 3.141592653589793
}
```

Comment: I am sorry but im still confused on how to apply this method to my code to make it able to receive float values

Comment: @tahakhamis You're trying to pass `_onDataReceived` where a function that takes a `Uint8List` is expected.  Change `_onDataReceived` to be `void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data)`, and then you can convert `data` to a `double`.

Comment: Hi, I am getting this error when I try to print : Unhandled Exception: RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: @tahakhamis That means you're calling it on an empty list...

Comment: But if the list is empty then it wont even get to that point because i have this condition: if(data != null && data.length > 0){

Comment: Here is my code:

void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data){
    if(data != null && data.length > 0){
      var doubleValue = data.buffer.asByteData().getFloat64();
      print(doubleValue);

Comment: @tahakhamis In that case, `data.length < 8`, so there aren't 64 bits to read a 64-bit `double` from it.  I've confirmed that a list that isn't long enough will confusingly produce that error message.

Comment: I am still getting the same error: Unhandled Exception: RangeError (byteOffset): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0

Comment: Note that if I print data with out converting the data type i get this results: [64, 148, 5] ( here the number i sent is 5 but i am not sure why i get always this 64,148 everytime i send a value)

Comment: @tahakhamis You have 3 bytes.  As I said, you need at least 8.

Comment: I am not sure if i get what you are saying correctly. Can you clarify please

Comment: @tahakhamis You printed your list.  It has 3 elements (3 bytes).  A `double` is a 64-bit value (8 bytes).  You cannot read 8 bytes from 3.  The data you received either is incomplete or does not represent a `double`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code to convert `Uint8List` to `List<double>`

```
List<double> convertUint8ListToDoubleList(Uint8List uint8list) {
    var bdata = ByteData.view(uint8list.buffer);
    return List.generate(
        (uint8list.length / 8).round(), (index) => bdata.getFloat64(index * 8));
  }
```

Is data type from your stream is Uint8List? If it is Uint8List, have you tried this code?

```
 void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data){
    if(data != null){
      chunks.add(convertUint8ListToDoubleList(data));
     

    }

    if (kDebugMode) {
      print(" chunks: , $chunks " );
    }
  }
```

If you use `List<double>chunks=[]` use `List<double> convertUint8ListToDoubleList(Uint8List uint8list)`.

Comment: I am still getting an error which says "The argument type 'List<double>' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<List<double>>'."

This is how the _onDataReceived look like right now:

void _onDataReceived(Uint8List data){
    if(data != null && data.length > 0){

      List<double> convertUint8ListToDoubleList(Uint8List data){
        var bdata = ByteData.view(data.buffer);
        return List.generate(
            (data.length / 8).round(), (index) => bdata.getFloat64(index * 8));
      }
      chunks.addAll(convertUint8ListToDoubleList(data));



    }}

Comment: Okay, you use `List<List<double>> chunks = <List<double>>[];`, I'll modified my code.

Comment: Why you use `List<List<double>> chunks` instead of `List<double> chunks`?

Comment: Do you mean something like this:   List<double> chunks = [];
?

Comment: I changed it to   List<double> chunks = []; ... The error is gone but now every time i send data from the other end i get this value: [1.1159333162470807e-308] no matter what is the value im sending

Comment: Can you print `Uint8List` data before you convert it?

Comment: If the List is "List<double> chunks" I get this error: The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<double>'. But if I change it to "List<int> chunks = [];" I get this reslut: [64, 144, 3] (The number I sent is 3) but every time i send any data I always get the first [64,144, (then the actual number i sent) ]

Comment: I/flutter (26063): [64, 144, 3] ( here i sent 3)
I/flutter (26063): [64, 144, 5] (here i sent 5)

Comment: If you got error "The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<double>'" it means you're trying to pass `Uint8List` to `List` double. Make sure you assign the right data type. I've used `convertUint8ListToDoubleList` function on my own project and worked.

Comment: I tried to print it before converting it as you asked me to do, so when i try to print it before converting it, it gives that error : The argument type 'Uint8List' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'Iterable<double>. Unless i change the List type from double to int then it prints it

Comment: When I use the "convertUint8ListToDoubleList ", I get the result as  [1.1159333162470807e-308] No matter what value im sending

Comment: I've added suggestion code `_onDataReceived`.

Comment: I get this reslut again chunks: , [1.1155586699285036e-308] :(